# spring inject bean invoke protected method occur error : NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, spring

the instance that spring inject invokes protected  method  normally , but has error log:NoSuchMethodException

code sample ：

```
@Autowired
private InsChecker insChecker;

public void test(Object ins ){
    DataMessage tmpMsg = insChecker.isAllowSend(ins);
}


@component
public class InsChecker extends BaseInsService {
 protected DataMessage isAllowSend(Object ins) {
 // method detail
 return CommonUtils.createSucccessMsg();
 }
}
```

Comment: isAllowSend should be public.

Comment: Maybe the method shouldn't be protected , it is design problem and it is  reflection problem

Answer (score 0):

create `No-args` constructor in the **@Component** class. This might work